# i am enabling SELinux in enforce mode but when i am rebooting my system crashed

Tags: apparmor, selinux

i have install uubuntu 22.04 and debain 11 on different oracle machince. i am enabling SELinux in enforce mode but when i am rebooting my system crashed

#### fist remove apparmor

1. `sudo systemctl stop apparmor -y`
2. `sudo apt-get remove appamror -y`
3. `sudo reboot`

#### Now install SELinux

1. `sudo apt-get install policycoreutils selinux-basics selinux-policy-defalut -y`
2. `sudo selinux-activate`
3. `sudo selinux-config-enforcing`

here i tried both ways mean through this command and from config file as well
from file command: `sudo nano /etc/selinux/config` here replace **SELINUX=permissive** to **enforcing**

and after this i am just rebooting my unbuntu or debain both machine crashed or showing this messages

[Screen after rebooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yebEY.png)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to install SELinux instead of AppArmor? Many elements of Ubuntu is really designed to work around AppArmor, so some amount of hacking may be required to replace it with SELinux.

Comment: I agree with @ArturMeinild. Although you *can* make SELinux work with Ubuntu if you're willing to put in a great deal of effort, Ubuntu is not the best distribution to use it with. If SELinux is the requirement, stick with Debian. If SELinux is a "nice to have", consider leaving it aside for AppArmor 

Comment: If SEL is a requirement, go Debian or RHEL-based distros, not Ubuntu.  AppArmor is the primary protection/confinement tool on Ubuntu so running both AppArmor and SELinux at the same time doesn't make sense AND will lead to weirdness in your system.  Also you should run SEL in permissive mode and then heavily watch your logs to see what *would* be blocked, and then adapt your SEL policies accordingly BEFORE putting to Enforce (this applies to ANY system)